# Activate android service remotely - even on locked device

Tags: android, service, remote-access

I am developing a kind of security app, that will trigger remotely (by an SMS). My question is: what is the best way to ensure that my activation SMS will activate the service even if the phone is locked?
I don't want to mess with the users to drain their batteries, normally the app does nothing, only if it's activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use a broadcast receiver declared in the manifest + an intentservice to perform what you want.

Declare the receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="yourpackege.YourReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
    <action   android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
    </intent-filter>
```

The receiver:

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    .
    .
    .
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)  {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
        SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        notifyMessages(context, messages);
    }       
}
```

And in notifyMessages trigger an intentservice that performs the real work. In this way the broadcast receiver will execute just the time to get the message (s). 
In this way you won't mess with the battery but you run some code only when the phone receives an sms.

```
private void notifyMessages(Context c, SmsMessage[] messages) {
    Log.d("SMS", "Received message");
    for(SmsMessage m : messages){
                if(isActivationMessage(m){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(c, YourIntentService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra(); // Put all your extras here
        c.startService(myServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: I thought the same, i was just not sure that the service will trigger in all circumstances. And what do you think, should I check the sms text in the receiver for the specified activation word, or run always the service, and do everything there? - I am asking this because of the mentioned battery drain.

Comment: The service should trigger in all circumstances, especially because the device was waken up by the sms. If you want to be super sure, check https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful . For the second question, I'd say it depends on what do you do for checking. Performing a bunch of ifs in the receiver is certainly less expensive than running an intent service since it involves allocating objects and running a new thread (even if the os performs pooling).